# How to get video stream information with RtspClientSharp library?

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, video-streaming, rtsp

I use [RtspClientSharp](https://github.com/BogdanovKirill/RtspClientSharp) to receive video frames from rtsp stream. The library allows just to receive the frames. But, I need to get information about the stream, such as bitrate, codec and etc. I don't see that there is currently an option for this in the library.

1. Do I miss something or I need to modify the RtspClientSharp code to support this?
2. Other alternative is to write a helper code in c++ which uses ffmpeg. I can use pinvoke to call c++ code which will connect to the rtsp stream (in addition to RtspClientSharp client), get the stream information and send it back to my c# code. Is this a better alternative?